# Is there a keyboard shortcut to move on to the next card in a list in Trello?

Tags: trello

Navigating from one open card to the next in a Trello list is effort intensive. One has to click outside the open card and then find the next card in the list (which can be tough if it's a crowded list) and then click it to open. That's a lot of work.

Is there any shortcut to easily navigate to the next card in a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a shortcut to navigate around the board view, but not from card to card while looking at them. We'll look into this, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Using <kbd>J</kbd> / <kbd>K</kbd> now navigates to card below / card above when viewing a card.

Comment: Not sure why this had negative votes as it does exactly what was asked: Navigating from an open card. The other answers require pressing Escape to get back to the list before you can start navigating.

Answer (score 3):

[Trello's Help page](https://trello.com/shortcuts) has all the keyboard shortcuts listed. The `Navigate Cards` section has what you need. -

[image]

As it says -

> Pressing the arrow keys will select adjacent cards on a board.

And then you can press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open it.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work (I'm using Windows + Chrome).

Comment: Works for me (Ubuntu + Chrome). Focus a card first with Tab key or mouse, then try the arrow keys.

Comment: The arrow keys work to move focus up or down a list for me, but not when a card is open.

Comment: You have to close a card first(You can use Escape key) and then move to next card.

Comment: Indeed, I can do that. But still not much of a shortcut. Hrrrmmmm.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the arrow keys to navigate on the board (and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open a card), you may press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to close the currently open card.

IMHO, pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd> is two too many keystrokes. I'd vote for the arrow keys to work on open cards too.